# questions regarding laravel sidebar

Tags: laravel

im new to laravel and i want to know how to make a dynamic sidebar.

Right now it looks like this

[image]

In my native language it means category - berrys, juice, candy - and each of them goes to a view, where there should be only products who have in the database one of these three in the "category" column.

My question are:

1)Can i do it with a foreach loop?

2)Do i need to make a model and controller for each of them and if i do what functions do i need?

3)How do i show only the produkcts that have the right category

Right now i have:

```
@foreach($products as $item)
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
      <a href="details/{{$item['id']}}">
        <div class="thumbnail">
        <img src="images/{{$item['galerija']}}" alt="...">
        <div class="caption">
          <h3>{{$item['nosaukums']}}</h3>
          <p>{{$item['cena']}}</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </a>
    </div>
    @endforeach
```

That shows every product. Do i need something similar?

More details.

In my controller:

```
function shop()
{
    $data= Product::all();

   return view('pages.shop',['products'=>$data]);
}
```

My moddel:

```
class Product extends Model{
protected $primaryKey = 'id';
public $timestamps = false;
protected $fillable = [
    'nosaukums', 'cena', 'kategorija', 'galerija', 'apraksts',
];
```

}

Comment: show us what is in `$products` array

Comment: @AbdullaNilam i added more detail. hope this is helpfull

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes.
2. Since it's the same model, you only need one controller with one method (if you follow conventions this would be a `show` method).
3. Using a relation.

Due to the fact you're coding in your native language (which I cannot decipher), below example is a way of how you *could* do it.

P.S. In the case that a product can have more than one categories, you should convert the relation into a [Many to Many](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many) using a pivot table.

#### Category model

```php
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Category extends Model
{
    public function products(): HasMany
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Product::class);
    }
}
```

#### Product model

```php
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Product extends Model
{
    public function category(): BelongsTo
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Category::class);
    }
}
```

#### Web.php

```php
Route::get('categories/{category}', [CategoryController::class, 'show'])->name('categories.show');
```

#### Sidebar view

Note: You can load `$categories` using a [View Composer](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/views#view-composers).

```html
<div>
    @foreach($categories as $category)
        <a href="{{ route('categories.show', compact('category')) }}">
            {{ $category->name }}
        </a>
    @endforeach
</div>
```

#### Category controller

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Models\Category;

class CategoryController extends Controller
{
    public function show(Category $category)
    {
        $products = $category->products;
        
        return view('categories.show', compact('products');
    }
}
```